# Can't create folder "com.examples.app"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, folder, project-server

I have tried to create various folders which name came after class packages and found that some can be created but not others. I've found that folders ending with possible extension e.g. ".app",".crt" throw an error when created. I've checked and .app and .crt are by default forbidden FILE extensions, so why does this rule affect folder creation? Also why is this not mentioned in the folder name rules? Who knows I would like to know if there is a workaround that will allow me to create desired folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into central admin and edit those extentions not to be forbidden ;) , there is a reason why they are as they could be reserved for other things or could be well known file formats for embedding virus / trojan ect...

goto **Central Admin**,

click on **Security**,

under **General** click on **Define blocked file types**

remove the file types you want to use! but doing this will allow users to upload those .filetype names into sharepoint site opening your site to vunrability ;) just be carefull!! known types should stay blocked like .exe ect

other solution is to programmatically do it! you can unblock the file type and the reblock it during the folder creation, but doing this tho will still leave a problem of the folder being blocked when viwing the folder location as its a blocked file type lol, so more config and messing around would make it horrid! rule of thum dont use blocked file types and change the naming convention to best practices!

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/8666.sharepoint-2010-best-practices.aspx

ok so you have com.examples.app but cant you trade it for com-examples-app in sharepoint? so any . become - that way you dont need to unblock the file types and keep the naming convention (almost)

**EDIT**

just to make it clear that folder names take the same conditions as file naming convention and physical file/folder naming convention:

> Folder Names and File Names
>
> o Do not use: " # % & * : < > ? \ / { | } ~
>
> o File names cannot be longer than 128 characters
>
> o Do not use the period character consecutively in the middle of a
>   file name. For example, "file..name.docx" is invalid.
>
> o You cannot use the period character at the end of a file name
>
> o You cannot start a file name with the period character

also

> You cannot use the following characters anywhere in a folder name or a
>   server name:
>
> • tilde
>
> • number sign
>
> • percent
>
> • ampersand
>
> • asterisk
>
> • braces
>
> • backslash
>
> • colon
>
> • angle brackets
>
> • question mark
>
> • slash
>
> • pipe
>
> • quotation mark
>
> • You cannot use the period character consecutively in the middle of a
>   folder name.
>
> • You cannot use the period character at the end of a folder name.
>
> • You cannot start a folder name with the period character.

https://faitbis-estus.fa.ua.edu/Shared%20Documents/Estus%20End%20User%20Training/SharePoint%20Invalid%20Characters.pdf

also like to make it clear that having a blocked .extention in a folder is also not allowed!

so `http://mysite:123/subsite/site/folder.exe.rtd/myfile.doc` as sharepoint will see `.exe` , `.rtd` and `.doc` as extentions

exe is a blocked file type, rtd isnot and would be excepted, doc is the actual file and is accepted.

to get around this do:

`http://mysite:123/subsite/site/folder-exe-rtd/myfile.doc`

that will indicate to sharepoint folder-exe-rtd is a folder and not a file and myfile.doc is the file within that folder! so in your case do the above or just dont use any blocked file types that it might think it is ;)

for a list of blocked file types by default in sharepoint is:

```
ade
adp
app
asa
ashx
asmx
asp
bas
bat
cdx
cer
chm
class
cmd
cnt
com
config
cpl
crt
csh
der
dll
exe
fxp
gadget
grp
hlp
hpj
hta
htr
htw
ida
idc
idq
ins
isp
its
jse
ksh
lnk
mad
maf
mag
mam
maq
mar
mas
mat
mau
mav
maw
mcf
mda
mdb
mde
mdt
mdw
mdz
msc
msh
msh1
msh1xml
msh2
msh2xml
mshxml
msi
msp
mst
ops
pcd
pif
pl
prf
prg
printer
ps1
ps1xml
ps2
ps2xml
psc1
psc2
pst
reg
rem
scf
scr
sct
shb
shs
shtm
shtml
soap
stm
svc
url
vb
vbe
vbs
ws
wsc
wsf
wsh
```

.app is one of them!

Comment: thanks for the quick answer - BUT important thing is that I want FOLDER not file to have certain name. Folder is not a file and my required name doesn't violates rules for folder name.

Comment: just ammended my answer